# retrieving values from dynamic generated radio button lists

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am adding a list of radiobutton lists dynamically to the page and on button click I want to store the selected values .i am following this sample code below.
How can I retrieve the selectedIndexes of these dynamically created RadioButtonLists? I've spent the better part of the day trying various fixes from other similar questions online, but have had no luck.
 If I use 'Inspect Element' in Chrome, I am able to see the RadioButtonLists in their desired locations ostensibly with the ID I have assigned (RBQuestion_1, RBQuestion_2, etc),

```
Sub BindForm()

Dim tblStars As New Table()
    Dim rb As New RadioButtonList()
    rb.ID = RBQuestion_" & row("Id")
    Dim tc As New TableCell()
    Dim tr As New TableRow()
    tc.Controls.Add(rb)
    tr.cells.Add(tc)

    tblStars.Rows.Add(tr)

    form1.Controls.Add(tblStars)
Next
end sub


 Protected Sub btnSave_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

For Each ctrl As Control In Page.FindControl(RBQuestion_" & row("Id"))
            If TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButtonList Then
                Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(ctrl, RadioButtonList)
                For i As Integer = 0 To rbl.Items.Count - 1
                    If rbl.Items(i).Selected Then
                        'get the  value of the selected radio button'
                        Dim value As String = rbl.SelectedItem.Value
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking inside the Page's control list.

Your radio buttons will not be there. They are inside the control list for the TableCell to which you added them.

You need to find your table, then step through each row, and for each row find the cell, then inside the cell, find the radio buttons.

Alternatively, you could try adding the buttons to an object-scope generic list control of type RadioButton as you create them. Then reference them directly from within your btnSave_Click event handler. **Pro:** Removes the need to navigate the control hierarchy. **Con:** Distances the code from the actual underlying implementation. This has the potential to be misleading regarding the true location of those controls when viewed by developers in the future... A set that may potentially include yourself after you've had time to forget what you did and why. For me, that's usually about 4 hours on a good day.

Therefore I prefer the navigate-the-hierarchy method as it is more true to how things are actually laid out. But I'm pretty sure that the generic list method will work too.

---

**EDIT**

I think the piece of the puzzle you're missing is overriding the CreateChildControls method.

I acknowledge your question was phrased in VB. But I'm crappy with VB, so I went with C# instead. Hope this makes enough sense to be usable to you.

Confirmed this works as expected in VS 2010 when hosting in the ASP.NET Development Server.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();

            this.CreateRadioButtons();
        }

        private void CreateRadioButtons()
        {
            var tblStars = new Table();
            tblStars.ID = "tblStars";

            ListItem opt1 = new ListItem();
            opt1.Text = "I like red";
            opt1.Value = "Red";

            ListItem opt2 = new ListItem();
            opt2.Text = "I like green";
            opt2.Value = "Green";

            ListItem opt3 = new ListItem();
            opt3.Text = "I like blue";
            opt3.Value = "Blue";

            var rb = new RadioButtonList();
            rb.ID = "RBQuestion_1";

            rb.Items.Add(opt1);
            rb.Items.Add(opt2);
            rb.Items.Add(opt3);

            var tc = new TableCell();
            var tr = new TableRow();
            tc.Controls.Add(rb);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            tblStars.Rows.Add(tr);

            form1.Controls.Add(tblStars);
        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var tblStars = this.form1.FindControl("tblStars") as Table;
            if (tblStars == null)
                return;

            foreach (TableRow row in tblStars.Rows)
            {
                foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    var rb = cell.FindControl("RBQuestion_1") as RadioButtonList;
                    if (rb == null)
                        continue;

                    var selectedValue = rb.SelectedValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My corresponding page markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply..if i create dynamic table in above bindForm method how can i access that table in save button event handler .it is not accessible in save event handler

Comment: You need to override the CreateChildControls method. Answer edited to provide an example.